# How to access downloaded sound in IsolatedStorage via URI (WP7)?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, uri, isolatedstorage, alarm

I basically downloaded a file name custom.mp3 into my isolatedstorage and I can see it via isolatedstorage explorer....

The question here is... How can I access the particular custom.mp3 via URI?

So far I got this.. but I wonder why it is not working:

```
alarm.Sound = new Uri("isostore:/custom.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: Have you tried new Uri("/custom.mp3", UriKind.Relative); i don't know if this will work but it is worth a try.

Comment: /custom.mp3 URI will only work if you attach the file together with your application when you compile. But thanks for your reply :D

Comment: I mean i tried that but it din work... the /custom.mp3 works only when I compile together wif my application...

Comment: yes you are right, it had to be part of the project to use this uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is wrong. Nothing else is wrong with your code. Post the code you're using for saving the mp3 file in the first place, if you want further help.

Comment: Urm.. the code goes like this:

string alarmfile = "custom.mp3";
                    isolatedStorageFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(alarmfile,FileMode.Create,isolatedStorageFile);
                    long songfilelength = (long) e.Result.Length;
                    byte[] songbyte = new byte[songfilelength];
                    e.Result.Read(songbyte, 0, songbyte.Length);
                    isolatedStorageFileStream.Write(songbyte, 0, songbyte.Length);
                    isolatedStorageFileStream.Flush();

Answer (score 0):

For easier reading, the code to store the MP3 goes something like this..

```
string alarmfile = "custom.mp3";
isolatedStorageFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(alarmfile,FileMode.Create,isolatedStorageFile);
long songfilelength = (long) e.Result.Length;
byte[] songbyte = new byte[songfilelength];
e.Result.Read(songbyte, 0, songbyte.Length);
isolatedStorageFileStream.Write(songbyte, 0, songbyte.Length);
isolatedStorageFileStream.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only files packaged in the XAML can be used as alarm sound:

> Remarks
>
> The Sound URI must point to a file packaged in the application’s .xap
> file. Isolated storage is not supported. When the alarm is launched,
> the sound is played quietly and then gradually increases in volume.
> There is no way to modify this behavior.

From:

[Alarm.Sound Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm.sound%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)