# How to access downloaded sound in IsolatedStorage via URI (WP8)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am struggling with this problem of accessing the sound file (mp3) download in isolated storage to be used in Alarm ,

The problem mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518408/how-to-access-downloaded-sound-in-isolatedstorage-via-uri-wp7)

I am getting this error:

BNS Error: The action request's sound uri is invalid

Please help me but remember I am using the sound file for Alarm
Regarding the code it is the same as the link above.

This is download and save code of the sound file :

```vb
Public Async Function DownloadFile(url As Uri) As Task(Of Stream)

    wc = New WebClient()
    AddHandler wc.OpenReadCompleted, AddressOf OpenReadCompleted
    AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf DownloadProgress

    wc.OpenReadAsync(url)
    Dim r As IO.Stream = Await tcs.Task
    Return r
End Function


Private Sub OpenReadCompleted(sender As Object, e As OpenReadCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.[Error] IsNot Nothing Then
        tcs.TrySetException(e.[Error])
    ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
        tcs.TrySetCanceled()
    Else
        tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result)
        Dim file As IsolatedStorageFile
        file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()

        Using Stream As IsolatedStorageFileStream = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("Sound.mp3", System.IO.FileMode.Create, file)

            Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}

            While (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
                Stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

            End While
        End Using


    End If


End Sub

Private Sub DownloadProgress(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Proind.Value = e.ProgressPercentage / 100
    Proind.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString & " %" & " ( " & (e.BytesReceived \ 1000).ToString & "/" & (e.TotalBytesToReceive \ 1000).ToString & " ) KB"
End Sub
```

Comment: try: `alarm.Sound = new Uri("/shared/transfers/custom.mp3", UriKind.Relative);`

Comment: tried it, Not working gives me the same error.

Comment: show how do you download and save the song

Comment: Anyone has any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set a file in the isolated storage as the sound of the alarm, and that's not allowed. Only files packaged in .xap can be set as sound source of the alarm:

> Remarks
>
> The Sound URI must point to a file packaged in the application’s .xap
> file. Isolated storage is not supported. When the alarm is launched,
> the sound is played quietly and then gradually increases in volume.
> There is no way to modify this behavior.

From:

[Alarm.Sound Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm.sound%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

However, there is a way you could use a downloaded song as alam's sound. In `OpenReadCompleted` method, instead of saving the downloaded file in the isolated storage, create a file using `File.Create` method, and store the data there. Then it will be possible to use this file as the alarm sound:

Here is the C# code, I think you will easily translate to VB:

```cs
byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

using (var fs = File.Create("file.mp3"))
{
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Then, you can set the Sound property of the alarm as:

```cs
alarm.Sound = new Uri("/file.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: Thank you ,But what is the purpose of this limited behavior?!

Comment: @alihaider I have no idea.

Comment: @alihaider you are lukcy, there is still a way you can use a downloaded song. See the edited answer. It's in C#, but you will easily translate it.

Comment: OMG It worked ! ,Thanks anderZubi ,I hope anyone who faces such a problem can benefit from this awesome work around.

Comment: I have an update, The sound file worked at first but after submission to store the downloaded version did not work .

Comment: It is giving me this error: Access to the path c:\Data\Programs\{GUID}\Install\Sound.mp3 is denied

Comment: Maybe, once deployed to the Store the statement of only songs packaged in the .xap will be supported may apply. I don't know the reason.

Comment: This is completely unreliable and restricted !